How to use previous state for showing previous card items with react native?
I have a React Native web app with a card item that shows category items. For example, parrots can have multiple categories, like: parrots1, parrots2, parrots3. If a user clicks on parrots1, this category can also have multiple subcategories, such as: parrots1.1, parrots1.2, etc. It's a one-to-many relationship.
A user can click on a card item and be navigated to the next card items with the categories. For example, category item 1 has subcategories: 1, 3, 5. This works fine.
Now, I want to implement a back button so that the user can return to the previous card items. I implemented a previous state reference using the useEffect hook, like this:
  useEffect(() => { 
    if (previousStateRef.current) {
      console.log("Previous state:", previousStateRef.current);
    }
  
    // Update ref to current state after render
     previousStateRef.current = subCatgoryList;
  }, [subCatgoryList]);

I can retrieve the previous state items, but I need to use this previous state with a button so that the user can see the previous card items.
I implemented a function to update the previous state reference, like this:
  const updatePreviousStateRef = (currentState) => {
    if (previousStateRef.current) {
      console.log("Previous state:", previousStateRef.current);
    }   
    previousStateRef.current = currentState;
  };

And I created a button for using that function:
 <Button icon="arrow-left" mode="contained" onPress={updatePreviousStateRef}>
        Back to Card
 </Button>

But this does not work. If a user press on the button. This will be returned:
Previous state: SyntheticBaseEvent {_reactName: 'onClick', _targetInst: null, type: 'click', nativeEvent: PointerEvent, target: div.css-text-146c3p1.r-maxWidth-dnmrzs.r-overflow-1udh08x.r-textOverflow-1udbk01.r-whiteSpace-3s2u2…, …}

So for brevity, this is the whole code:
import { ActivityIndicator, Pressable, StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import { Button, MD2Colors, Searchbar } from "react-native-paper";
import {
  CategoryList,
  LoadingContainer,
} from "/src/components/general/view-flatlist-card";
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

import { AccordionCategoryItemsContext } from "../../../services/accordian-category-items.context";
import { AccordionItemsContext } from "../../../services/accordion-items.context";
import { AnimalDetailToggle } from "../../../components/general/animal-detail-toggle-view";
import { AntDesign } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { ButtonDetail } from "./animal-detail.screen";
import { SafeArea } from "../../../components/utility/safe-area.component";
import { SearchAnimalContext } from "../../../services/search-animal.context";
import { Spacer } from "../../../components/spacer/spacer.component";
import { SubCategoryInfoCard } from "../components/subcategory-info-card.component";
import { ToggleContext } from "../../../services/toggle.context";
import { fetchSubCategoryData } from "../../../services/category/category.service";
import { useNavigationState } from "@react-navigation/native";

export const SubCategoryScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const [subCatgoryList, setSubCategoryList] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const { performSearch, results, setInput, input } =
    useContext(SearchAnimalContext);
  const { toggle, showAccordion } = useContext(ToggleContext);
  const [toggleIcon, setToggleIcon] = useState(true);
  const { accordionCategoryItems } = useContext(AccordionCategoryItemsContext);
  const { accordionItems } = useContext(AccordionItemsContext);
  const [isSearchbarFocused, setSearchbarFocused] = useState(false);


  const previousStateRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchSubCategoryData(route.params.subcategories).then((data) => {
      setSubCategoryList(
        data.animals.length > 0 ? data.animals : data.subcategories
      );
      setLoading(false);
    });
  }, [route]);

  useEffect(() => { 
    if (previousStateRef.current) {
      console.log("Previous state:", previousStateRef.current);
    }
  
    // Update ref to current state after render
     previousStateRef.current = subCatgoryList;
  }, [subCatgoryList]);

  const handleSearchChange = (text) => {
    setInput(text);
    if (text.length === 0) {
      performSearch(""); // Clear results when the input is empty
      navigation.navigate("dieren");
    } else {
      performSearch(text);
    }
  };

  const handleToggle = (itemId) => {
    toggle(itemId);
    setToggleIcon(!toggleIcon);
  };


  const updatePreviousStateRef = (currentState) => {
    if (previousStateRef.current) {
      console.log("Previous state:", previousStateRef.current);
    }   
    previousStateRef.current = currentState;
  };




  return (
    <SafeArea>
       <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
      <Button icon="arrow-left" mode="contained" onPress={updatePreviousStateRef}>
        Back to Card
      </Button>
    </View>
      
      {isLoading && (
        <LoadingContainer>
          <ActivityIndicator animating={true} color={MD2Colors.green200} />
        </LoadingContainer>
      )}
      <Searchbar
        placeholder="Zoek een dier"
        value={input}
        onFocus={() => setSearchbarFocused(true)}
        onChangeText={handleSearchChange}
        onBlur={() => setSearchbarFocused(false)}
        style={styles.searchbar}
      />
      {results.length > 0 ? (
        <AnimalDetailToggle />
      ) : (
        <CategoryList
          data={subCatgoryList.filter((item) =>
            item.name.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase())
          )}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <>
            {console.log(item.id)}
        
              <Pressable
                onPress={() =>
                  navigation.navigate("groepen", { subcategories: item.id })
                }
                disabled={isLoading || (!item.animals && !item.subcategories)}
              >
                <Spacer>
                  <SubCategoryInfoCard subcategories={item} />
                </Spacer>
              </Pressable>
              <View>
                {(item.subcategories || !item.animals) && (
                  <ButtonDetail onPress={() => handleToggle(item.id)}>
                    <AntDesign
                      name={toggleIcon ? "downcircle" : "upcircle"}
                      size={19}
                      color="green"
                    />
                  </ButtonDetail>
                )}
              </View>
              {item.subcategories &&
                item.animals &&
                showAccordion.includes(item.id) &&
                accordionCategoryItems(item)}
              {(!item.animals || !item.subcategories) &&
                showAccordion.includes(item.id) &&
                accordionItems(item)}
            </>
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        />
      )}
    </SafeArea>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  searchbar: {
    marginBottom: 10,
    borderRadius: 0,
  },
});

Question: how to navigate with the back button to the previous card items?

React won't re-render when updatePreviousStateRef is called, even if the ref does get updated. This is because refs by design aren't hooked into react's render cycle. Can you use useState instead of a ref?

The reason for this SyntheticBaseEvent object showing inside of you ref is because you are taking an argument in the updatePreviousStateRef method and passing it down to the button which if you look into the docs, it passes down an event argument inside the onPress method.
You have to change the way updatePreviousStateRef is being called, by passing the correct state inside the method argument.
Also if you are planning on re-rendering the page to show the new categories vs the old categories, you'll need to save the values inside a state variable via useState instead of saving it inside a refObject, because in React, changes to the ref object won't cause a re-render inside the component, so the changes won't reflect.

After a lot of try/error.
I came to this solution:
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

    function usePrevious(value) {
      const ref = useRef();
    
      useEffect(() => {
        ref.current = value;
      }, [value]);
    
      return ref.current;
    }
    
    export default usePrevious;

And then I use this function in the SubCategoryScreen:
 const previousState = usePrevious(subCatgoryList);   

  const updatePreviousStateRef = () => {
    if (previousState) {
      console.log("Previous state:", previousState);
      setSubCategoryList(previousState);
    } else {
      console.log("Previous state is null or undefined.");
      setSubCategoryList([]); // Provide a fallback value
    }
  };

